# Regex to retrieve only numbers from string while iterating dict?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to retrieve the following `2019/2020 (dddd/dddd)`from a string that can look like this `FA WSL Cup Season 2019/2020`. The common factor is that the desired content always comes last. so while iterating i would like to extract that by using regex, but I do not know any regex. So psuedo example below:

```
for i in cont.values():
    label = PERFROM REGEX ON i['label']
    season_info[abbreviation] += [APPEND REGEX VERSION]
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can use RegEx to extract such data:

```
import re

result = re.findall( r'(\b(\d{4}/\d{4}\b)', 'FA WSL Cup Season 2019/2020')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['2019/2020']
```

Let me break the solution down for you:

**\b** refers to a word break and will work for both spaces and end of lines.
**\d** means any digit (any number).
The **{4}** means that I want 4 digits (one after the other, a repetition of 4).
The **/** will simply be the character separating the two 4 digits groups.
Using **()** I instruct RegEx that this will be the group I want to extract.

I also suggest to use online RegEx testers to learn and also to test your regular expressions.

Here's two examples among the ones I use:

- https://regexr.com/
- https://regex101.com/

Here's a beginner course that I find simply great:

- https://regexone.com/

Comment: Very informative, thank you so much for taking your time to post this! Don't got any excuses to not learn regex now!

Comment: Small questing, does a string that you perform regex on always return a list or is that optional?

Comment: What if the string were "12345/67890 birthday 2018/2020 FA WSL Cup Season 2019/2020"? The OP seems to appreciate the regex primer but SO would be a mess if all answers included such extraneous material.

Comment: Good point, @CarySwoveland!
Changed the code, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad that I got your interest, @MisterButter! Check the course I linked it is great.
About your question re.findall returns a list (check its documentaiton: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html )

Comment: I deleted the extra material, @CarySwoveland, I just tried to help but fully agree with your point.

Comment: @Pitto No worries at all, thank you for providing the links and a crash course in RegEx

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you delete the extras in this case, as the OP appreciated it. Go ahead and put it back if you want (or perhaps better, include a link to a regex primer in a comment on the question).